# BMW E60 (525d M Sport 2005 UK). Cranking but not starting. Fuel Pump/Relay issue?

Tags: starting, fuel-system, bmw, relay, fuel-pump

**Background**:

Long term bad earth problem has been causing iDrive to crash and reboot for years. Bad earth seems to drain the life of the battery over a period of a few years. On my 3rd battery now. Never been able to find the bad earth. I am told there are some 140 earth points and it could be any of them?? A new CCC at £3300 never solved the problem, so reluctant to spend more. Living with it.

---

**New Problem**:

Car is cranking but no firing. This has worsened over the last year to the point now where no amount of cranking works. It used the fire when I turned the key right back and then to ignition point a second time. Fuel prime twice seemed to help.

I am told by a mechanic that it could be the fuel pump. Apparently there are three. One in the Tank, one in the engine bay, and he feels it could the one between them under the passenger seat.

Question. I want to check the Fuel Pump relays. How many are there? Where are they? Enormous gratitude to anyone who knows the answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to dig out some E60, diesel-specific information if I have time, but consider the following as possible culprits:

- clogged fuel filter
- faulty fuel pump relay
- weak fuel pump